Salesforce Mobile SDK SmartStore Encryption (React-Native)
Our team recently developed a custom mobile app using Salesforce Mobile SDK (version 12.0.1) and utilized the SmartStore feature for local data storage. After conducting a penetration test on the app, we discovered that the SmartStore database files are not encrypted.
We would like to understand if there is a built-in way to enable encryption for SmartStore within the Salesforce Mobile SDK or if additional configuration is required on our end.
Questions:

Does the SF Mobile SDK ensure that all data within SmartStore soups is encrypted automatically, or are there certain data types or fields that require manual encryption?
How can we verify that the encryption is successfully applied to SmartStore soups, both globally and at the field level?
Are there any known limitations or bugs in the current version of the Salesforce Mobile SDK (12.0.1) we are using related to data encryption in SmartStore?
Is there any additional configuration needed in the React Native app to fully encrypt data for each SmartStore soup? Below is the screenshot of the code on how to register the soup.

We are unable to share the details of the un-encrypted file on this public platform as they are confidential, but can share it with your SF team in a meeting or in another private manner.
Below is the testing methodology conducted during the penetration testing:
Prerequisites:

Jailbroken iPad 7th Generation (iPadOS 18.0.1)
Decrypted IPA file (Company QA mobile app)

Decrypted IPA file is dumped from the device using a tool called frida-ios-dump (https://github.com/AloneMonkey/frida-ios-dump)
IPA file is unmodified; It is only decrypted for reverse engineering and testing purposes


iMazing (https://imazing.com/)

Testing Methodology:

Install iMazing on host system. iMazing will be used to browse the iPad 7th generation file system
Setup the testing device:
2.1. Jailbreak the iPad 7th Generation (includes installing Sileo and packages inside Sileo such as Frida, Ellekit, PreferenceLoader, openssh)
2.2. Install the decrypted IPA file (Company QA mobile app)
Use the mobile application for some time to generate data in storage
Browse to the location of 'store.sqlite' and copy the database file to host system
Use tools like sqlitebrowser to the open 'store.sqlite' copied to host system


Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to include your code in text format, not as a screenshot.
